# Change language of SupaBase error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

### Hello stackoverflow!

Does anyone knows if you can change the language of a error message from **SupaBase** when a user Register/Login.

**Example**: User tries to register without email, the error is "Please enter a valid email adress"

I want to be able to change the error message. :)

Code:

```
<!-- language: javascript -->
const handleSignUp = async (email, pass, username, kon) => {
console.log(email, pass, username, kon);

setLoading(true);
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp(
  {
    email: email,
    password: pass,
  },
  {
    data: {
      username,
      kon,
    },
  }
);

error ? seterrorMessage(error) : console.log(data);

setLoading(false);
};
```

Comment: Seems pretty simple. Instead of printing out the supabase error message, print out your own.

Comment: Not possible. So its not that simple. The error message comes from there system. If a user tries to register with a email that allready exsist i would need that info from SupaBase.

Comment: I get that. I'm saying that when you call seterrorMessage() you provide your own custom error message instead of the one from supabase. You presumably control what is displayed to the user in this application. You can have it show anything you want, or nothing at all. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** -> Get the status code of the error and make a message for each error code. :)

**How to get error code?**

```
Console.log(error.status)
```